# Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm running mysql5 on Mac os x 10.5.8 and got this error.
How do I solve this?

The DB worked fine but stopped working after system update.
I think its something related to the socket file which is /tmp/mysql.sock
do I need to give it special permissions and owner?

Thanks

Comment: What programming language ? What are you doing when you get that error ?

Comment: The problem is solved.
The problem was in my certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. The problem was in my certificate
Make sure you're using the correct one.